Forecast Model - Python - SARIMA
I am having trouble in applying a SARIMA model to my data set in Python - I am using store sales data of a department store and want to forecast the next year split into quarters. The data has stationarity and I have cleansed to split into quarters of the historical data. Data source goes to 31/12/2017.
See below the Python code and the output
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX


model = SARIMAX(quarterly_sales, order=order, seasonal_order=seasonal_order)
results = model. Fit()

forecast = results.get_forecast(steps=4)
forecast_index = pd.date_range(start='2013-01-01', periods=4, freq='Q')
forecast_series = pd.Series(forecast.predicted_mean, index=forecast_index)


print(forecast_series)

# Plot the historical quarterly sales data
quarterly_sales.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(10, 6), label='Historical Quarterly Sales')

# Check if the forecast index aligns with the expected future quarters
print(forecast_series.index)

# Overlay the forecasted sales with more visibility
plt.plot(forecast_series.index, forecast_series, color='red', marker='o', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, label='Forecasted Quarterly Sales')


plt.ylim(0, max(quarterly_sales.max(), forecast_series.max()) * 1.1)


plt.title('Quarterly Sales with Forecast')
plt.xlabel('Quarter')
plt.ylabel('Sales')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)


plt.legend()

plt.show()


new_index = [f"Q{date.quarter} {str(date.year)[-2:]}" for date in forecast_series.index]
forecast_series.index = new_index

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


historical_index = [f"Q{date.quarter} {str(date.year)[-2:]}" for date in quarterly_sales.index]
quarterly_sales.index = historical_index


quarterly_sales.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(10, 6), label='Historical Quarterly Sales')


plt.plot(forecast_series.index, forecast_series, color='red', marker='o', linestyle='dashed', label='Forecasted Quarterly Sales')

plt.title('Quarterly Sales with Forecast')
plt.xlabel('Quarter')
plt.ylabel('Sales')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)


plt.legend()

plt.show()

AS above is what I have tried but I cannot see any of my forecast on my visualisation graph as specified split into quarters for the upcoming 12 months despite it showing on the screenshot on the legend.

Could be a tick location issue if the x axis is Date. Internally, matplotlib will convert dates to numeric locations with values matplotlib.dates.date2num(your_dates). If you overlay some other data, and it has a different x axis, then it might end up off-screen. The other issue could be non-finite predictions from the model - are you sure the model is fitting ok? Without some sample data it's hard to be more specific.

Hello, yes so this is a sample of my data set - any further guidance would be greatly appreciated
date                  family        sales onpromotion
01/01/2013 AUTOMOTIVE 0 0
01/01/2013 BABY CARE 0 0
01/01/2013 BEAUTY 0 0
01/01/2013 BEVERAGES 0 0
01/01/2013 BOOKS 0 0
01/01/2013 BREAD/BAKERY 0 0
01/01/2013 CELEBRATION 0 0
01/01/2013 CLEANING 0 0
01/01/2013 DAIRY 0 0
01/01/2013 DELI 0 0
01/01/2013 EGGS 0 0
01/01/2013 FROZEN FOODS 0 0
01/01/2013 GROCERY I 0 0
01/01/2013 GROCERY II 0 0
01/01/2013 HARDWARE 0 0
01/01/2013 HOME AND KITCHEN I 0 0

Yes, of course - see link here https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlSTo3w1bKG1hdcfk3QKnIlBn8YOeA?e=DXfNwq

The example below shows forecasting and plotting for synthetic quarterly data. Is this the type of output you were after?

trn window: 2000-03-31 to 2009-12-31 [ 40 samples] | abs % err:   47.23 | target: -0.493, forecast: -0.260
trn window: 2000-03-31 to 2010-03-31 [ 41 samples] | abs % err:    8.14 | target: -0.624, forecast: -0.573
trn window: 2000-03-31 to 2010-06-30 [ 42 samples] | abs % err:   51.47 | target: -0.515, forecast: -0.780
trn window: 2000-03-31 to 2010-09-30 [ 43 samples] | abs % err:   21.35 | target: -0.892, forecast: -0.702
trn window: 2000-03-31 to 2010-12-31 [ 44 samples] | abs % err:   28.81 | target: -0.717, forecast: -0.924
trn window: 2000-03-31 to 2011-03-31 [ 45 samples] | abs % err:   18.18 | target: -0.629, forecast: -0.743
...

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.tsa.api as tsa

#
# Synthetic quarterly data
#
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', '1/1/2025', freq='QE')
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi * 4, len(dates))
sine = np.sin(t) * np.exp(-0.03 * t)
data = sine + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, dates.size)

df = pd.DataFrame({'signal': data}, index=dates) #index is the date

#
# Define SARIMA model
#

#Training start date
train_start = df.index[0] #"31/03/2000"
min_train_size = 40

#Forecasting will start after 40 samples, until end of the data
forecast_start = train_start + min_train_size * df.index.freq
forecast_end = df.index[-1] #"31/12/2014"

forecasts = []
for train_end in pd.date_range(forecast_start, forecast_end, freq=df.index.freq).shift(-1):
    #the "shift(-1) is so we stop one sample before the forecast date
    train_data = df[train_start:train_end]
    
    #Fit the model and get the results object
    results = tsa.ARIMA(
        train_data,
        order=(3, 1, 0),
        seasonal_order=(1, 0, 0, 20)
    ).fit()
    
    #Use results object to forecast the next sample
    forecast = results.forecast()
    forecasts.append(forecast)

    #
    #Report results for each forecast
    #
    forecast_date = forecast.index.item().date()
    assert forecast_date == (train_end + df.index.freq).date()
    
    actual = df.loc[[forecast_date]].values.item()
    
    print(
        f'trn window: {train_start.date()} to {train_end.date()}',
        f'[{train_data.size:>3d} samples] |',
        f'abs % err: {abs(1 - forecast.item() / actual) * 100:>7.2f} |',
        f'target: {actual:>+5.3f},',
        f'forecast: {forecast.item():>+5.3f}',
    )

forecasts_df = pd.concat(forecasts, axis=0)

#
# Plot data and forecasts
#

#Plot the signal
ax = df.plot(
    y='signal', use_index=True, xlabel='date', ylabel='signal',
    marker='.', color='dodgerblue', linewidth=1, figsize=(8, 2)
)

#Plot the forecasts
forecasts_df.plot(
    use_index=True, label='forecast', color='crimson', ax=ax
)

#Add some visual lines marking various dates
[ax.axvline(date, ymax=0.05, linewidth=5, color='tab:green')
 for date in [train_start, forecast_start, forecast_end]
 ]

ax.legend(ncols=2, fontsize=8)


Hello, this is exactly what I need and to conclude the data a year past the last entry point in the data
